# Make vignette only affect one layer (Photoshop)

Tags: adobe-photoshop

So, I'm pretty new to photoshop and I need some help.

I have a .png logo with a transparent background. On a new layer, I'm trying to put a vignette over the image (to give it a shaded look out the outer parts of the image), but the vignette ruins the transparency.

Is there a way to make the vignette only show up on the image and not anywhere that's transparent?

Thanks!

Comment: Can you show what you're trying to do? It's hard for me to visualize it.

Comment: I'm not sure how else to explain it. I'm trying to put a vignette on an image, without it ruining the transparent background.

Answer (score 2):

Apply a clipping mask to the vignette layer. Yup, just answered my own question. I've been trying everything for the last couple hours and I just figured it out.

I have my two layers (image and vignette). I just added a clipping mask to the vignette and it worked! Easy peasy once I found it.

Answer (score -1):

It sounds like you are trying to achieve a masking effect, where the vignette will be hidden on areas that are not transparent.

To achieve this, Ctrl + Click the logo layer to select all non-transparent items. Then click on your vignette layer and from the menu click "Layer > Layer Mask > Reveal Selection".

This will create a layer mask on the vignette layer that only shows over your logo.

Comment: I don't know if I'm doing it wrong or something, but this isn't working. The vignette still shows up on the edges of the image, ruining the transparency.

Comment: Your approved answer "Create a Clipping Mask" operates in nearly the exact same way as my suggested solution. The only difference lies in the number of layers used. For further reading, check out: https://www.webascender.com/blog/photoshop-masking-clipping-vs-layering-masks/